# Activity.setTurnScreenOn(true) does not turn the screen on

Tags: android, android-activity

I need my app turn the screen on in case of an activity switch, even if the user did press the "Power" button before. We are using either no lockscreen, or the simple "swipe" lockscreen only (no secure locks).

The following code seems to solve the problem:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED)
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON)
}
```

but the documentation says those flags are deprecated, and the corresponding `Activity` functions should be used instead:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27) {
        setShowWhenLocked(true)
        setTurnScreenOn(true)
    }
}
```

This version does not work at all. I've tested in on API 27 and API 29 devices. Maybe some other thing is missing, or maybe `AppCompatActivity` is not compatible with the new functions?

Note: specifying these flags in the manifest also works, at least for devices with at least level 27.